# Does a Page of spell knowledge allow a caster to use a magic device if both hold the same spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items

Say a sorcerer had a [page of spell knowledge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge/) with [cure light wounds](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cure-light-wounds/) and a [wand](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wands/) of cure light wounds. Would the page of spell knowledge allow them to cast from the wand without [UMD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device) checks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your specific example doesn't work.

Wands use the [Spell Trigger](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Spell-Trigger) activation method, which says -

> Spell trigger items can be used by anyone **whose class can cast the corresponding spell**. This is the case even for a character who can’t actually cast spells, such as a 3rd-level paladin.

So, as long as the user's class can cast the spell, the user can activate the wand.

Alas, the [Page of Spell Knowledge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge/) says -

> If the bearer is a spontaneous spellcaster and **has that spell on her class spell list**, she may use her spell slots to cast that spell as if it were one of her spells known.

So, a Sorcerer cannot use a Page of Spell Knowledge to enable casting of Cure Light Wounds, which also stops him from using a Wand of CLW. And, a Sorcerer can also already activate wands containing spells on the Sorcerer/Wizard list, even if he does not have those spells in his list of Spells Known.